# TAB key does not work in MFC application on COM framework. But, arrow keys work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, mfc, atl

My application is a dialog shipped out as a dll. It can be launched in modal and modeless modes,from a bigger application that I have no control of. We use MFC library and follows COM architecture.  For development purpose we have a tester application that launches my dialog.

The problem I face is that tab key do not work at all in both modal and modeless. 
but, arrow keys work.

When observed through SPY++, I cannot see tabs coming to my dialog at all.

I am pretty confused on what's happening ?

Comment: Do the controls all have the `WS_TABSTOP` property?

Comment: Yes they do.. all of them.

Answer (score 1):

For tabs to work in a modeless dialog, the application must call `IsDialogMessage` from its main message pump. But in your case, the application doesn't even know the dialog exists. I believe your only option is to install a Windows hook (see `SetWindowsHookEx`) and call `IsDialogMessage` yourself.

Modal dialog should work out of the box though - are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I am surprised as well that modal dialog's tab doesn't work as well.(Since modal owns the message pump). I made the exact changes as per the following link by installing a hook and adding callback to it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187988 (Only variation is that I have a dialog instead of property sheet)

Comment: Looking at the following link, which is pretty much my case, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233263. Where I am writing the dll and the application launches my dialog via dll. But,the code sample they gave out confused me. In both the methods they used a variable hwndDllDlg and I am not sure what that dialog is and how to initiate it.. @Igor Tandetnik do you know ?

Comment: In one case, `hwndDllDlg` is the name of the parameter to `DllDlgProc`. In the second case, I imagine it would be a name of a global variable or something, wherein the `HWND` returned by `CreateDialog` is stored.